# How to find the default app that handles the intent when multiple apps are returned by queryIntentActivities()?

Tags: android

I'm actually looking to determine the default Dialer app that's installed on the device. I've gotten a list of installed apps that can handle a specific intent, but I don't see any way to check which one is set to be the default one. Here's the existing code:

```
val infoList = pm.queryIntentActivities(Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL))
for(resolveInfo in infoList) {
    val app = resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName
    val isDefault = resolveInfo.isDefault
}
```

However, the `isDefault` flag always returns as false. I also considered using `RoleManager`, but that only tells you if your app is the defaultone, not which app is actually set as default.

Any suggestions?